# Integrating Zurb Foundation 5 into a Wordpress 3.8 Theme

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I'm looking for the "proper" way to infuse Wordpress 3.8 with Zurb Foundation 5, in such a way that it's upgrade proof.  I've found only one site that gives instructions on how to do this, but it has me overwriting the built-in jQuery version directly in wp-includes - http://naileditdesign.com/making-foundation-5-framework-no-conflict-in-wordpress/.  Is there any other suggestions that might be a better solution, and have a bit longevity?

I'd really like to start using Foundation 5 within a Wordpress theme, but I'd like to be doing a proper job of it right from the start.

Answer (score 2):

It is a really good idea to use noConflict with foundation scripts on wordpress. If this isn't done you will only end up having problems with plugins later.

I found the only part that needed changing to achieve this was the script before the closing  tag that initialises foundation. You can do it like this:

```
function guts_initialise_foundation(){ ?>
    <script>jQuery(document).foundation();</script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'guts_initialise_foundation', 200 );
```